# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK] even though on latest API

Tags: android-studio

I'm new at programming and I was basically trying to load up the app I created onto my phone. But I keep getting the following message :- Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]
It makes no sense to me because My minsdkversion is set to 8 and my device is running Kitkat. 
I've attached my Manifest.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
       </activity>
      </application>
    </manifest>
```

And this is my Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.Daki.learning"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
   }
}

    dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
 }
```

Comment: Why not test your app via the emulator first, to rule out a possible problem with your phone?

Comment: Yes, the new 'beta' (0.8.0 series) for Android-Studio appears to be buggy...a number of us are all seeing that error.  [ See the other postings here in this same forum on this same issue. ]  I've gone back and installed the older Android-Studio...another choice is to use the Eclipse IDE to do your development, for a few more months, or whatever.